# Custom function formula working in one cell but not another

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to save a formula as a custom function for a co-worker as it keeps coming up that she needs it. I finally managed to get it to work - on one cell. But it's not working on another cell.

Data:

*result needed*   45.00   486.00

*result needed*   43.50   108.00

The formula in Excel is `=ROUNDUP((D16/C16)*4,0)/4`

I think in the VBA Module it is

```
Function RoundQuantity(Amount, Rate) As Integer
   RoundQuantity = Application.RoundUp((Amount / Rate) * 4, 0) / 4
End Function
```

When I call this function from Excel, I am using `=RoundQuantity(D16,C16)` and it successfully rounds from 10.48 to 11.00, but it rounds 2.48 to 2.00.

Just to explain the function, I am trying to round up the Quantity (first column) to the nearest quarter.

Please help?

Comment: What exactly does `nearest quarter` mean? By nearest quarter of a unit? Because if so, then wouldn't `10.48` be rounded up to `10.5`?

Comment: Wouldn't CEILING worksheet function work as easily? `=CEILING(D16/C16,0.25)`

Answer (score 1):

While I don't entirely get the term `nearest quarter`, the reason why you're evaluating to `2.00` is simple--your function is returning an integer. Just change `Function RoundQuantity(Amount, Rate) As Integer` to `Function RoundQuantity(Amount, Rate)` and it should return `2.50`, provided it's formatted correctly as well.

See my screenshot below:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: @user3216628: Kindly accept the answer if it helped you. Be mindful of the rules of SO. You're welcome and good luck.